# How to obtain freqs & percentages for all categorical vars in df

Tags: r, percentage, frequency-analysis

My df, Chap3, has ~50 categorical variables. I want to produce a frequency table for each categorical variable that also includes percentages. The code below works fine for the single var bsex but I cannot figure out how to repeat it for all categorical vars. Have tried using variants of apply, using `select_if(is.factor)`, etc, to no avail.

```
    Chap3 %>% 
        count(bsex) %>% 
        mutate(percent = round(n / sum(n) * 100,1))
```

Answer (score 1):

For such cases it is better if you get the categorical data in long format.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

Chap3 %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = where(is.factor)) %>%
  count(name, value) %>%
  group_by(name) %>%
  mutate(n = round(prop.table(n), 1)) %>%
  ungroup

#   name  value   n
#  <chr> <fct> <dbl>
#1 bsex      0   0.4
#2 bsex      1   0.6
#3 csex      0   0.5
#4 csex      1   0.5
```

**data**

It is easier to help if you provide data in a [reproducible format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269)

```
set.seed(123)
Chap3 <- data.frame(id = 1:10, 
                    bsex = factor(sample(c(1, 0), 10, replace = TRUE)), 
                    csex = factor(sample(c(1, 0), 10, replace = TRUE)))
```

Comment: For someone trying the same thing, I had to add a couple of tweaks to produce precisely freqs and percentages. The code is as follows (sorry for my newbie formatting errors): Chap3 %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = where(is.factor)) %>%
  count(name, value) %>%
  group_by(name) %>%
  mutate(percent = round(prop.table(n) *100, 1)) %>%
  ungroup

Answer (score 1):

We may use `table/proportions` from `base R`

```
proportions(table(stack(type.convert(Chap3[-1], as.is = TRUE))), 2)
      ind
values bsex csex
     0  0.4  0.5
     1  0.6  0.5
```

#### data

```
Chap3 <- structure(list(id = 1:10, bsex = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("0", "1"), class = "factor"), 
    csex = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L
    ), .Label = c("0", "1"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```